# Core data NSFetchRequest also fetches children objects of the Entity

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm new to iOS dev and Core Data. I have a parent NSManagedObject

```
@class Units;
@interface Properties : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * descr;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * city;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * state;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *zipCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * imageKey;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * numberOfUnit;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * thumbnailData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage * thumbnail;
@property (nonatomic) double orderingValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *units;
```

And a Child:

```
@class Properties;

@interface Units : Properties

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * unitDescr;
@property (nonatomic) int16_t unitNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Properties *property;
```

When I fetch the Parent Properties with this method to display the parent Properties objects in a tableview:

```
- (void)loadAllItems
{
    if (!allItems) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *e = [[model entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Properties"];
        [request setEntity:e];

        NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor
                                sortDescriptorWithKey:@"orderingValue"
                                ascending:YES];
        [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sd]];

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (!result) {
            [NSException raise:@"Fetch failed"
                        format:@"Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
        }

        allItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];
    }
}
```

I run in to a problem where the core data context fetches the child objects of the Parent Entity. I just want to return the Parent Objects.

For example, If I have a property with 3 units, the properties tableview should display just 1 row but it is displaying 4 rows (1 parent and 3 childs).

How do I just return the parent objects?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show what you're getting? Maybe put in a loop and NSLog each element in `allItems` at the end of that code. Without seeing either the results or how you're displaying them its hard to say which of those two is the actual problem. Maybe you're getting too many records, or maybe the way you're displaying them is actually displaying parent + each Units record attached to that parent.  Need more info.

Comment: plz check, your table may be data in you table is in different structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define *Properties* as parent entity of *Units*, then every *Units* object is also a *Properties* object. Therefore fetching properties returns also all units.

This is probably not what you wanted. You should just define the relationships between *Properties* and *Units*, without setting a parent entity (so that both classes are direct subclasses of `NSManagedObject`).

Remark: I would call the entities *Property* and *Unit*, because each instance represents a single property or unit.

Answer (score 16):

Take a look at `NSFetchRequest`'s `setIncludesSubentities` method. If your data model reflects your inheritance pattern in your code, then your fetch request won't fetch children entities if you've set it properly.

`NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.includesSubentities = NO;`

Comment: @EverydayImSeeSharping: This is a good answer, and please don't get me wrong. But you should think about whether you really want to define "Units" as a **child entity** of "Properties". That implies that "Units" inherits all attributes of "Properties", so "Units" will also have address, city, state ... attributes. It also means that both entites are stored in a common SQLite table instead of 2 separate tables.  - It is probably not necessary to set parent/child entities in your case, you can just define the relationships.

Comment: you are right, I ran through a debug and po the unit set as a child, it inherits all parent's attributes plus have the parent as a property (relationship). I guess I can just get to the parent of the unit by doing unit.property. In the SQL world, Property and Unit tables obviously have a parent-child relationship. So in what case, should I use parent-child relationship in core data?

Comment: @EverydayImSeeSharping: If you have entities sharing a common set of attributes, e.g. Animal as parent entity of Dog and Cat. It is the same thing as defining a subclass of a class. - Parent/child entities have nothing to do with relationships.

Comment: Yep, this was what I was looking for too. Cheers!