# Fetch only Parent entity's data in Core Data where Parent Child entity has 1 to M relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, fetch, relationship

[image][image]I have 2 entities. **Country** and **Region**. Country to Region has 1 to Many relationship. If I fetch country(by CountryID predicate) it returns specific Country properties with all relative Region.

In my case I don't need Region data(contains huge data). How it possible?

Following thread saying, **includesSubentities** of NSFetchRequest can do that. But its not working for me!

[Core data NSFetchRequest also fetches children objects of the Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331376/core-data-nsfetchrequest-also-fetches-children-objects-of-the-entity)

Comment: Could you show how country and region are defined? I don’t understand if country is the parent entity of region or if they have an one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Country to Region relation is 1 to M. You can call **Country** is the parent entity of the **Region**

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n41bf.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq0dp.png

Comment: Absolutely, I just got a little confused by the title. Isn’t includeSubEntities only relevant for inheritance?

Comment: You shouldn’t fetch any region objects as long as you don’t access any attributes from Region.

Comment: In Swift its **includesSubentities**. I am about to fetch Country only. But fetchRequest fetching regions as well (there has relation)

Comment: As @JoakimDanielson says, the concept of parent entities and subentities is akin to class inheritance and is very different from the concept of relationships between entities.  `includesSubentities` is therefore irrelevant for your purposes.

Comment: @SolidLine, have you modified the Country class with any other properties or functions?

Comment: No, I didn't. (Both are subclass of NSManagedObject) - [Joakim Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson)

Comment: Well there must be something to fire the faults, care to show us your code when fetching?

Answer (score -1):

The default for an `NSFetchRequest` is `true` for [`returnsObjectsAsFaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506756-returnsobjectsasfaults) so unless you have changed this property your regions will only be *faults*, not the full objects.

You can further limit the data that is fetched by supplying only the properties you are interested in via the [`propertiesToFetch`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506851-propertiestofetch) property.

You should, as always, be wary of pre-optimising; if performance is an issue then you can look at it, but I would doubt that even fetching several thousand `Region`s as faults would have a performance impact.

Comment: You are saying to fetch with **fault fire**. But my query is not on that point.

Comment: I also said that if you don't want the `regions` then don't include that property in `propertiesToFetch`.  Do you want me to expand on that section of my answer? The point is that unless you reference a property of one of the related regions, the related regions *are not fetched*, they are merely faults.